# Why is the change of <title> element in index.html not reflected in the cypress interface?

Tags: html, vue.js, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have been trying to understand the cypress file & folder structure when used with cucumber and vue.js but it's been driving me crazy, especially when different sources say different things. My problem is I wrote the following test:
[screenshot of source code and browser element inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbtc0.png)

This is the [Cypress output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCnMg.png)

When I open my website locally on chrome, I see clearly that the title element has been changed.  Why is test in cypress still not passing when it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For checking the title you have to use `cy.title()`. So in your case it would be:

```js
cy.title().should('eq', 'User Registration')
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize it was a syntax error on my part.  could you recommend any good resources to learn cypress with cucumber?

Answer (score 0):

it has been like this for most ide that are online the title appears when you just don't use third party tools like cypress and use a normal ide and save it on the file running without running and saving using other sites online....
even if you open and take a look at the code using CTRL + SHIFT + I it will show you the code and there you can clearly see that the title haven't been changed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).